# Very simple element to be coded in bootstrap responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm good in HTML CSS, but beginner in responsive design like Bootstrap 3.
So i need to know how to make the design on the image in Bootstrap.
It should be one row on descktop screens and two rows on smaller screens like portrait tablet and smartphones.

Thank you in advance.[call-to-action image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9wpi.jpg)

Comment: show us your efforts.

Comment: .cta-section a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 1em 3em;
}

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/aLgrte2g/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center box">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>Contact: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid black; 
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Now on smartphone screens the button is too big, i'm receiving padding for both paragraph, how to solve this

Comment: Please check: http://elvimebeldizajn.com/

Comment: Delete this `[class*="col-"] {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}` from `2035.responsive.css`

Comment: Also take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/aLgrte2g/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could structure you HTML like the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
            Request a list of the latest materials
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
            Contact: info@lojalstik.mk +334
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14100/

Please take a look at the docs for a better understanding of the grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: That's not gonna work for me, i need different solution, please take a look here: http://elvimebeldizajn.com/

Comment: @LjubisaTrajkov oh man don't put your password here!

Comment: It doesn't matter i can change it later.